# Difference between 大半 and 多数派

Tags: word-choice, words

I understand that both 大半{たいはん} and 多数派{たすうは} can be translated as "majority". Is there a difference between them in usage or nuance?

Comment: 大半 is about number, 多数派 is about 派 "faction".

Answer (score 2):

I think the major difference is that 大半{たいはん} means that it must be more than half of the total group, but that 多数派{たすうは} only needs to be the subgroup with the largest number of people.

That is to say in Japanese, 多数派 could be used to translate the English word `plurality` wherein there is no absolute majority (no one has more than half of the total group), but there is one group that has the largest fraction of the votes.